# Is it possible to index the entered text in the textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, parsing, textarea

Good evening! I have a question about whether it is possible to index the entered text in the text field and manipulate the data.

For example, I now want to index the entered text and distribute it by words and add it to the array in a unique way.

Then write the output word array to a specific file, cookies or temporary cache.

For example: the user enters 10 words and starts indexing the text.

For example: this can be used if, for example - the user entered the word `"stackoverflow"` and the second time he tries to write the same word `"stackoverflow"` then we need to use this autocomplete to display this word and the user will only choose the word.

Answer (score 2):

You can save all the words in a string to an array like this:

```js
let result = [];
let text = "Hello, I am a cookie monster";

result = text.match(/\b\w+\b/g);
console.log(result);
```

Now you can use the array to do whatever you want to do with it.